# jquery ui slider Styling

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to style a value within a jquery ui range slider handle.

I'm using this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6hyVP/2/)

Plus I've used this CSS and it's still not working.  Where am I going wrong?

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id="slider-vertical" class="sliderControl-label v-labeCurrent"></div>
</div>

.sliderControl-label {
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
}

.ui-slider-handle .sliderControl-label .v-labelCurrent {
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    top: -2px;
    transition: color 0.15s linear 0s;
}​


$(function(){
    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').text(ui.value);
        },
        create: function(event, ui) {
            var v=$(this).slider('value');
            $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle .sliderControl-label .v-labelCurrent').text(v);
        }
    });    
});​
```

I'm getting my self in a right CSS mess.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What are you trying to accomplish that isn't working?

Comment: I'm trying to style the value inside the handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have fixed this. Thank you for your help guys. My issue was me not declaring the class of the value in the javascript.

```
$(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').html('<div class="value-label">'+ui.value+'</div>');
```

By Declaring this line, I could then style the value inside the handle. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

use `.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle` as your CSS selector (and declare these styles below the jQuery UI CSS file).

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/6hyVP/10/)

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    width:2em;
    left:-.6em;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Hi mdm..The only thing with this is if I want to style the handle and also style the text inside the handle...How do I do this?

Comment: what specifically can't you style with the above selector?

Comment: I can't style the text within the handle which is also styled.  Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnystudent/VycW2/)You'll see how I want the text to be within side the handle.  In the fiddle, one slider works, the other one is static.  I want the one which works to look like the static one @mdmullinax

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to style that number in the handle all you need to do is target the `.ui-slider-handle` like so: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hyVP/8/):

```
.ui-slider-handle {
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```